# Failed to start the session: already started by PHP ($_SESSION is set) for facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, symfony-2.4

I'm implementing facebook app in symfony. I used facebook php SDK

When I call

```
$me=$facebook->api("/me");

    if(isset($me['id']))
        $response=$facebook->api("/".$me['id']."/notifications",
                "POST",
                array (
                        'access_token'=>$accesstoken,
                        'href' => 'notification',
                        'template' => $message,
                ));
```

In Symfony action I'm getting:

```
Failed to start the session: already started by PHP ($_SESSION is set)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think it simply means that somewhere prior to the execution of this code `session_start()` was called.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code right after the initialization of $me var.

```
$session = $this->get('session');
 $session->start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You add a @ sign in from of `session_start()` to suppress the error. This way, you can keep the line of code incase the session wasn't previously started, but the error will be hidden in case it was already started:

```
@session_start();
```